# Error in Derived type declaration: Variable at (1) in this context must be constant

Tags: fortran, fortran90, derived-types

I have a derived type declared in a module like this:

```
MODULE dmotifs
TYPE :: PRM
    INTEGER, PRIVATE :: nsp=4,nrx=8,maxprx=4
    REAL, PRIVATE :: cref=1e-6,tref=1
    REAL, DIMENSION(nrx,maxprx) :: k
    REAL :: input
END TYPE PRM

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE unreg(y,param,r,s)

    TYPE(PRM), INTENT(IN) :: param
    REAL, DIMENSION(param%nsp), INTENT(IN) :: y
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(param%nsp,param%nrx), INTENT(OUT) :: s=0
    REAL, DIMENSION(param%nrx,1), INTENT(OUT) :: r=0
    REAL :: mOut, mCtrl, pOut, pCtrl
    mOut=y(ind_mOut)
    mCtrl=y(ind_mCtrl) 
    pOut=y(ind_pOut)
    pCtrl=y(ind_pCtrl)

    ! <some operations on "r" and "s">
    RETURN 

END SUBROUTINE unreg
END MODULE dmotifs
```

On compilation I get this error:

```
Error: Variable 'nrx' at (1) in this context must be constant
```

What is the meaning of "must be a constant"; should it be immutable during compilation i.e. like a PARAMETER?

But there is another issue, I cannot declare PARAMETERS within derived types. How to deal with this error? Would moving these objects out of the derived type and making them PARAMETERS, be the only option?

Most importantly I wish to understand why does this happen.

I was compiling using gfortran: `gfortran -Wall -c "dmotifs.f90"`

Comment: @VladimirF The entire part is huge. It contains subroutines that use this type.

Comment: You could have easily extracted the definition to a separate source file to show the problem is just there. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve But actually, it was more than enough here to include the complete error message *including* the 1 pointing to the offending line. I did not notice the other occurence of `nrx` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Declaring an explicit-shape array in a non-parameterized derived type requires a constant expression. You could either

- make `k` `allocatable,dimension(:,:)` (and (de-)allocation), or
- make `nrx` and `maxprx` global/module constants (or replace them right away).

If your [compiler supports it](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status), you can use [*parameterized derived types*](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v5n2a4.htm):

```
  type :: PRM(nrx,maxprx)  ! parameterized derived type definition
    integer, len :: nrx
    integer, len :: maxprx
    real         :: k(nrx,maxprx) 
    ! ...
  end type PRM
```

(Taken and adjusted from [here](https://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v5n2a4.htm).)

Comment: Just a small query: Is there any obvious advantage of using fixed size array here? This array just holds data that needs to be referenced by different subroutines. So I am not going to re-allocate it ever.